# MRUnit - Not Working as expected

Tags: hadoop, hbase, mrunit

I am having only mapper class that creates files for bulk loading into HBase and I have written a MRUnit for Unit testing.

Though the expected result and the retruned results are same, the MRUnit is failing with the message  **"Missing expected output"**.

Expected output: `(4b 65 79 31, {"totalColumns":1,"families":{"default":[{"timestamp":9223372036854775807,"qualifier":"default","vlen":6}]},"row":"Key1"})`

Actual output: `(4b 65 79 31, {"totalColumns":1,"families":{"default":[{"timestamp":9223372036854775807,"qualifier":"default","vlen":6}]},"row":"Key1"})`

Where am I going wrong ? 
Is it problem with ImmutableBytesWritable Or Put ?

Comment: What's the Mapper output key and value class types?

Comment: And what version of MRUnit?

Comment: Output key class type : ImmutableBytesWritable
,Output value class type: Put....

MRUnit version: 0.9.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So your failure is the fact that MRUnit is using the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the objects to compare the expected and actual output objects (a HashMap is used in the  `org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.buildPositionMap(List<Pair<K2, V2>>)` method):

- [ImmutableBytesWritable](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/ImmutableBytesWritable.html) - Does implement an `equals` and `hashCode` method
- [Put](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html) - Doesn't implement an `equals` or `hashCode` method

So the Put is what's causing the problem. The only way around this is to manually check the driver output (use the driver `run` method rather than `runTest`) and compare the result List to what you're expecting using the objects `compareTo` method (which does exist for both classes).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by setting a Comparator for Key and Value. Code below for a BytesWritable value.

```
    ReduceDriver reduceDrive = ReduceDriver.newReduceDriver(<<ReducerInstance>>);

    reduceDriver.setValueComparator(new Comparator<BytesWritable>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(BytesWritable o1, BytesWritable o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```